# Automated Email Campaign with filtered data

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, automationstudio, filters

In my current environment, we have multiple automated email campaigns setup in this way.

For one such campaign, there is a designated source DE which will be only be growing on demand which contains the leads.

As this will be an automated campaign, a Data Filter is defined for this DE to filter out "fresh data" by looking at a datestamp field.

In a typical scenario, one email template will be used for a campaign and will be setup using a User-initiated email approach. For the recipients option, it will be pointing to the said Data Filter.

Then, in the Automation Studio, One Filter activity will be created based on the said Data Filter. In the automation itself, that activity will be designated to Step 1, and then in Step 2, a Send Email activity will be dropped in using the User-initiated email mentioned before. The schedule option is setup for daily runs just for context.

All these seemed to work well but I've only started to question the need for Step 1 if Step 2 is already referencing the data filter in the recipient option. I feel like Step 1 is redundant.

If anyone has run into the same scenario or can shed any light on this, that will be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using data filters as the target audience in your send, then there is no need to use a 'group refresh' or 'filter activity' interaction.  These are used to produce a sendable list or DE based on the filtered data - which if you just send to the filter is unnecessary.

Another benefit to sending to just the filter is that for the VAWP link, it will use the 'Master' (or Source) DE for processing - meaning that as long as the subscriber remains there, the VAWP link will continue to work. Where as in a filtered DE, if they are removed from that DE, the VAWP link may break - providing a less then optimal users experience.

See [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/82663/exacttarget-sending-email-to-filters-vs-sending-email-to-filtered-data-extensi) for a great answer on a similar question.

Comment: Hi Gortonigton, 

Thanks for responding to my query once again, whatever you said make sense and I share exactly the same sentiments. I have decided to do some tests regarding this and hopefully our theory proved to be correct. I shall refer to the thread for reference.

Thanks Lege!